# Weak Topology is weaker than the usual Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

In the book of Brezis Functional Analysis, Section 3.2 , Definition of Weak topology on Banach space is given which is quite clear and in the next line we have an argument

**[image: here is the pic of the definition]**

But I didn't understand it clearly , which usual topology on $\phi_f$ are they talking, how is that continuous.

Comment: The usual topology is the topology induced by the norm. $\phi_f$ is continuous in this topology, since $f$ is in the dual of $E$, which is defined to contain only the continuous linear functionals.

Comment: @Carucel  thanx for the suggestion , I have answered my question see if it's correct..